# How does one import group data from a graphml file into NodeXL

Tags: graphml

I've been experimenting with importing graphml into NodeXL and am excited about how clean that is.

I still have not found an easy way to import group data as part of my graphml file?

Any hints would really be appreciated: More specifically I am hoping someone will point out the xml tags and attributes I can use so that nodelxl recognizes that certain vertices belong in certain groups.

Thanks,

MM.

Answer (score 0):

Groups are not yet imported from GraphML.
This is a useful feature request, we will get the work item on the pending list.
A work around is to add group membership data as a vertex property.  You can then use the NodeXL "Group by Vertex Attribute" feature after importing the GraphML file.

Regards,

Marc